# Ejecutar misma funcion en un for javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Hola que tal amigos tengo una duda tengo el siguiente código,
le explico en el php hago el recorrido del array que es variable su tamaño
muestra todo bien pero en el evento onclick del boton se envía siempre el primer valor del recorrido almacenado en el imput, cuando hago en los demás botones clic siempre me da el primer valor nose donde es
el problema en el js o el php.

CODIGO PHP

```
<script type="text/javascript" src ="script.js"></script>
<?php 
$datos1 = $array;
$longitudx = count($datos1);
for($i=0; $i<$longitudx; $i++){
?>
<?php echo $datos1[$i]['numeroPartida']?>
<input id="numpartida" name="numpartida" type="text" value="<?php echo $datos1[$i]['numeroPartida'] ?>">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="enviar" value="Detalle" href="javascript:;" 
onclick="DetallePatida($('#numpartida').val());">
<?php
}
?>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

CODIGO JS

```
function DetallePatida(numpartida) {
     var parametros = {"numpartida":numpartida};
$.ajax({
    data:parametros,
    url:'resultado.php',
    type: 'post',
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor");
    },
    success: function (response) {   
        $("#resultado").html(response);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Puedes poner el resultado de ese código, que es lo que te muestra, por lo que imagino, eso te esta creando múltiples inputs y botones, pero todos los imput tendrán el mismo ID, por lo que puede ir por ahí el error, quizás si le concatenas un numero para diferenciarlos, puede que ya funcione como quieres.

Comment: El problema es que estás dando el mismo `id` a todos los elementos y luego en el `onclick` pasas a `DetallePatida` en parámetro de ese `id` duplicado (`numpartida`). Cuando intentas alcanzar un elemento con id duplicado JS tomará el primero que encuentre. Aunque no da error aparentemente, los normas HTML dicen que no es posible dar el  mismo id a varios elementos en el mismo DOM. Para resolver esto puedes pasar el valor del elemento clickeado usando `this`, por ejemplo: `onclick="DetallePatida($(this).val());` De todos modos pon un `id` con un número secuencial o algo así.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tenés es que no estás armando de manera dinámica los IDs de los inputs. Al tenerlos dentro de un loop, terminás con IDs duplicados (`id="numpartida"`) y los IDs tienen que ser únicos.

```
<?php
$datos1 = $array;
foreach ($datos1 as $i => $dato) {
?>

<?php echo $dato['numeroPartida'] ?>

<input id="numpartida<?php echo $i ?>" name="numpartida[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $dato['numeroPartida'] ?>">

<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="enviar" value="Detalle" href="javascript:;" 
onclick="DetallePatida($('#numpartida<?php echo $i ?>').val());">

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola mi estimado excelente tu respuesta.

Comment: Exacto, así como dice el compañero, podrías incluso hacerlo un arreglo, para que quede un poco más limpio: `...$('#numpartida[<?= $i ?>]')...`

Comment: @luisfer correcto, pero según la versión de PHP que se esté usando, puede que tenga que tener habilitado [`short_open_tag`](https://www.php.net/ini.core#ini.short-open-tag).